# Create empty project from empty git repo

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have an empty git repository sitting here, and I'm trying to figure out how to get Intellij to start using it. I'm not that familiar with git, but traditionally, to initialize it from the command line, I'd just git clone it and git push it, but when I try to do something similar for Intellij, it doesn't seem to work.

The first thing I tried was to create a new empty project and then checkout from version control, but it won't let me do that because it requires that the directory not exist.

The second thing I tried was instead of creating a new project, to checkout from version control directly in the main page (I'm using Idea 14). Neither of these have worked, though I am quite new to this so I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!